# Is it possible to use postgresql libpq in android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libpq

I'm developing an app using android ndk in c++.

How can I use the libpq library client in Android?
I'm unable to find the libpq for ARM, so, is it possible to compile it for ARM?

I tried using Visual Studio 2019 , I created a project to build an Android Library, and added the source from postgresql but the library fails to build as it seems to depend from winsock2 and such.

Is this the way? Do I need some preprocessor options I do not know?

Comment: Please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: libpq is a native mode API for psql service which may be hard to implement on Android, sadly, because apps are sandboxed. Qt's implmentation switches to JDBC too, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can, you shouldn't.  A mobile app should NEVER directly connect to a backend DB.  Doing so would require you to have your password embedded in the app, with mininal obfuscation.  This means anyone with rudimentary reverse engineering skills can break it down and find the password, giving them total control over your data.

Instead, what you should do is have a web service between your app and the db.  All requests go to the webservice.  That service authenticates the user, and the password for the db is stored on the server, so it never leaves your control.  This minimizes the damage a malicious user can do to your infrastructure.

Comment: This is very true.
However, I'm trying to port an existing linux aplication to android, and It uses a conector with libpq to access de data. While it would be optimal to use this approach, it would require a lot of refactoring on the existing app, having the rest of it being crossplatform.

Comment: btw, is for internal use only. Not for a public apk.

Comment: @diego.martinez I still wouldn't do it.  For security, your DB shouldn't even be accessible to the outside world, it should be firewalled off an internal only.  That isn't possible with this approach.  You greatly increase your risk just by having it publicly accessible to the internet.

Comment: ok, I will do so, thank you for your advice